# ESLint - Prefer declaring variables together only when they are using destructuring of the same variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm looking for a way to make the below refactoring via ESLint auto-fix rules, is it possible?

Current:

```js
const foo = {}
const { bar } = foo
const { baz } = foo
```

Desired:

```js
const foo = {}
const { bar, baz } = foo
```

Comment: I don't believe there is an existing rule for this currently - might be worth considering writing a proposal to a plugin like `eslint-plugin-unicorn`.

Comment: @BradZacher Thanks, tracked [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/issues/2092).